# Neo4j index not finding Node

Tags: java, indexing, nullpointerexception, neo4j

I tried to follow the documentation and I ended up with this piece of code for Neo4j 1.8:

```
graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder( BASE_FOLDER + NEO4J_PATH )
            .newGraphDatabase();

registerShutdownHook();

//Check if there are any indexes
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(graphDB.index().nodeIndexNames()));
Index<Node> testIndex = graphDB.index().forNodes("test");

Transaction tx = graphDB.beginTx();
try {
    String nameKey = "name";
    String nameValue = "Gevorg";

    //The following 3 lines will be commented out 
    //when I run the program the second time
    Node me = graphDB.createNode();
    me.setProperty(nameKey, nameValue);
    testIndex.add(me, nameKey, nameValue);

    Node meAgain = testIndex.get(nameKey, nameValue).getSingle();
    System.out.println(meAgain.getProperty(nameKey));

} finally {
    tx.finish();
}
```

This prints the following as expected:

```
[] //There is no index at the very beginning
Gevorg
```

After the program terminates, I commented the creation of the node/index and I run the program again to hit a NullPointerException (meAgain is null). The index is retrieved correctly since the program prints `[test]` first but then `Node meAgain = testIndex.get(nameKey, nameValue).getSingle();` fails to retrieve the node. I tried both with and without using the Transaction. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark your Tx as successful, before calling `tx.finish`

```
tx.success()
```

HTH

/peter